# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ibm_db2.dll'

Tags: php, apache, xampp, db2

I want to install the db2 extension for PHP on Windows but it just isn't working. I've tried a lot of different solutions but I still get these:

[php.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrwUy.png)

[phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dCYZ.png)

[When I try connection to db2 database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Tmg.png)

I'm using Apache on XAMPP on port 80. I have installed this: https://github.com/ibmdb/php_ibm_db2/tree/master/PHP%207.4.x/x64/TS
and placed it in my C:\xampp\php\ext folder
and set "extension=php_ibm_db2.dll" in my php.ini file. (which is in C:\xampp\php)

[Only "db2" appearing in phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NXcQ.png)

[Variable where db2 is appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Xz3.png)

[PATH variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXlPy.png)

Comment: Look further down the `phpinfo()` output for a section that will itemise `DB2`

Comment: Did you __also__ download and install CLIDRIVER as described on https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2 ?   ( you only need this if you do NOT already have a db2 client on the PATH ).

Comment: See [here for other requirements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.requirements.php)

Comment: idk wich one to install in the list. Is it --> ibm_db2-1.9.6.1.tar 03-Feb-2015 05:10 1.2M  ?

Comment: You only need a CLIDRIVER when you do __not__ already have any Db2-client (or Db2-server) installed locally on Microsoft-windows.  If your Db2-server is remote (or in a container)  then you need  `ntx64_odbc_cli.zip` . If your Db2-server (or db2-client)  is running on the same hostname as PHP then its directories need to be on the PATH when php runs.   You can use `php -m | find /i "ibm"` to see if the db2 interface module loaded.

Comment: the php command (php -m | find /i "ibm") isn't returning anything (only the same error) when I execute it in cmd in my php directory (wich is C:\xampp\php ). So I guess I have to install the CLIDRIVER right ?

Comment: Please use plain text, not pictures/graphics in your question.  Is there a Db2-product already installed on the workstation? Give details, in plain text., in your question . The dependency looks like:  php --> php_ibm_db2.dll --> db2 cli driver --> db2-server.

Comment: How do I check if there's a Db2-product already installed ? with db2ls command ? db2 commands aren't working in my cmd (I guess I need path var ?)

Comment: The startup errors you're getting suggest the DDL does not match your PHP installation: PHP version, architecture, thread safety... But at first sight everything should be correct. 

Answer (score 0):

So, I did not manage to connect to my db2 DB with the db2 extension, but here's an alternative I've found -->

```
$database = "xxx";
$hostname = "xxx";
$user     = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$port     = 50000;

# Build the connection string
$driver  = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};";
$dsn     = "DATABASE=$database; " .
           "HOSTNAME=$hostname;" .
           "PORT=$port; " .
           "PROTOCOL=TCPIP; " .
           "UID=$user;" .
           "PWD=$password;";

$conn_string = $driver . $dsn;

# Connect

$conn = odbc_connect( $conn_string, "", "" );
if( $conn )
{
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    odbc_close( $conn );
}
else
{
    echo "Connection failed.";
}
```

output -->
Connection succeeded.

source -->
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2woc?topic=programmatically-php